# Using 'percent' data type displays 7500 instead of 75

Tags: salesforce

I am creating a one field data type is Percentage. i am adding a value 0.75 in formula for displaying the value 75 % on Display field.its the displays 7500 instead of 75.

NOTE: I recently update my managed package API version to 56.0

I Accepting the displays 7500 instead of 75.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZnqC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fn49E.png)